# Facebook page - post to users wall(after the user has liked the page)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I hope it's not that complicated but since Facebook has changed its API a lot(concerning permissions and so on) I find many outdated info which doesn't really help me.
The situation is:

1. I got a Facebook page with Page Tab
2. I got a Facebook-App which is associated with that page(via the tab).
3. My own WebApp posts via Facebook PHP-SDK to the wall of the page and each user sees the news in the stream.

Question: How can I post to the users timeline via that app?

My code so far(which posts to the wall of the page)

```
require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
$user = $facebook->getUser();

$page_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");
if( !empty($page_info['access_token']) ) {
    $args = array(
        'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token'],
        'message'       => "Neuer Test!"
    );
    $post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
} else {
    $permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");
    if( !array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0]) || 
        !array_key_exists('manage_pages', $permissions['data'][0])) {
        header( "Location: " . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "publish_stream, manage_pages")) );
    }

}
```

This is working fine, but the message is not available in the timeline of the users who liked the page, only in their own stream. Is it possible to publish to their timeline?

Comment: Ask the user to login to your application and make sure you have publish_stream permissions, Once you get the permissions and the user is logged in. You can post to their wall by making a POST request to "/me/feed" with the required parameters (Check Docs). But i don't think that's allowed by FB (The user should be aware that your app will publish otherwise you're probably breaking FB's Platform TOS). You might wanna check their TOS before implementing such things as FB might restrict publish rights of your app.

Answer (score 0):

dont know if you still need help. but just in case, this code works for me. It assumes you have a logged in user. and it posts to the user's timeline. this code doesn't get the permission which i believe, you need to work on since Facebook has Platform TOS. try this one:

```
     require_once('libs/facebook.php');

    // init new facebook class instance with app info (taken from the DB)
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => 'your app id here',
        'secret' => 'your app secret here'
    ));



    $fb_user_id = $facebook->getUser();
    $location = "". $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_stream'));

    if ($fb_user_id) {
        try {
            $fb_user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');   

        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            $fb_user_id = NULL;

            print '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> top.location.href="'. $location .'"; </script>';
            die();
        }
    } else {

        print '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> top.location.href="'. $location .'"; </script>';
        die();
    }


    $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                            array(
                            'link' => 'www.google.com',
                            'message' => 'Google me!'
                                             ));
```

Comment: on your code above, does it post even if user (not admin) likes the page? i have tried it with my other account which set as user, but it didn't post. it only post when the admin uses the page.